# Kate forces itself to be the default application for HTML

Tags: kde, file-association, kde5, kate

In the last few days, Kate took over opening HTML links and files. I want to get it back to Firefox, so I opened System Settings, went into Applications -> File Associations, found the text/html setting, and moved Kate below my browsers. Imagine my surprise when, after clicking Apply, Kate jumped back up to the top! Also, opening a link through xdg-open still launches Kate. That's not supposed to happen, right? Is this a bug? Or is there something else I need to do?

Environment:

- Kubuntu 15.10 (current on updates)
- Kate 15.08.2

Comment: Maybe -  Bug 354179 - File associations cannot be changed if already defined in $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/mimeapps.list  - https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=354179

Comment: That does look like the problem I'm having. Thanks @user26687, that's some good searching.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Making the suggestion by @user26687 the "official" answer...

This [bug is already filed at kde.org](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=354179) against the KDE kcm_filetypes component.

I used the suggested workaround:

> A workaround on the user side is to merge `$HOME/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` to `$HOME/.config/mimeapps.list`, and create a symbolic link to `$HOME/.config/mimeapps.list` at `$HOME/.local/share/applications`. **System Settings** then works fine.

It sort of works. Sometimes (most of the time?) moving things up and down doesn't properly apply. Also, if I open `mimeapps.list` in a text editor and move things around manually, the **System Settings** dialog doesn't reflect it. However, at least I can open links in Firefox now.

Comment: for those not wanting to read through the thread just run this: 
ln -sf ~/.config/mimeapps.list ~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list

Comment: Some associations kept coming back here as well, after hitting Apply or running `kbuildsycoca5` in a terminal. They came from .desktop files (location shown in the Edit dialog).

Answer (score 0):

Having the same problem, I tried the solution mentioned in the original post, namely moving kate downwards in the list of applications registered for HTML. The difference is: I moved it downwards by three rows (clicked three times on "Move down").

When clicking on Apply, Kate only jumped one row upwards. So a possible solution is to set Kate below the desired postition, then click "Apply" and see it jump right at the desired position.

I don't know if it applies for everyone experiencing this problem. I hope it will help a few people...